# spring boot war without tomcat embedded

Tags: spring, maven, war, spring-boot

I want to create a war file without embedded tomcat with maven.
Here the relevant part of my pom

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add tomcat only if I want to run directly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

How ever if I run mvn package I get a war, where the tomcat*.jar are in a provided-lib folder but still in the lib-folder. I read [build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging), but can't find what's wrong.

I know a main idea is to run it as an application, how ever our customer want's to deploy it on his application-server.

Comment: The fact that the jars are still there doesn't mean you cannot deploy it as a war. You can perfectly deploy it as is. Make sure that you exclude tomcat from the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

Comment: @niels, you edited this question, and since revision *2* it includes the answer to your question. What about reverting to your initial answer and providing a separate answer?

Comment: @Abdull good idea. It makes it more clear.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Following the Hint from M. Deinum I excluded the tomcat-depedency.

With the following pom.xml (relevant snippet) a `maven clean package` has the result I want to get.

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add tomcat only if I want to run directly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

**Warning for idea-user**: You must activate "Include dependencies with the provided scope" in the run-configuration (see [Unable to start spring-boot application in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064537/unable-to-start-spring-boot-application-in-intellij-idea) for more information)

Comment: But if the spring-boot-starter-tomcat is commented out, how do you run the app? I tried it this way, and deployed it to a tomcat container, but got error messages then. All similar to: org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
WARNING: Unable to load class [org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.NameRule] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.NameRule etc.

Comment: You can deploy the war in an arbitrary servlet-container. If your application doesn't need tomcat classes it works fine this way. Is it possible that you need at compile-time the tomcat-classes? How do you compile? mvn from commandline? Make sure you make a mvn clean at the beginning.

Comment: I use gradle, I already figured it out though. The build process (bootRepackage) produces two artifacts, one with and one without the embedded Tomcat container. Turned out I took the wrong artifact for the external Tomcat deployment - should take the war without the embedded Tomcat then.

Comment: SUPERB! Thank you very much.

Comment: When i run my application with above suggestion, it gives me error "Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown"

Comment: @Tatkal I Think it's difficult, to give you help with so less information. I can only guess that you have configured JMX at the logback config. I would recommend to open a new question with detailed information. Have you checked twice that the error only happens if you make the adjustments in pom.xml?

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if that's the spring-boot way of doing it, but you can exclude the tomcat jars using the `maven-war-plugin` configuration. That is, add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Using this approach, the war generated is not executable (cannot be run on command line using java -jar ) but can only be deployed to any servlet container

Answer (score 5):

I had this same need but removing the mentioned dependency didn't worked. I was able to get the WAR file by adding this `<packaging>war</packaging>` dependency to my pom file.

I used this [Spring](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/) article as a guide... sharing so this may help other people as well.

Answer (score 5):

Changing spring-boot-starter dependency from

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

To this one will exclude the embedded tomcat server.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way to build a final WAR from your existing Spring Boot project without embedded Tomcat is the following:

1) Set WARpackaging for your artifact: `<packaging>war</packaging>`

2) Set the Tomcat Server dependency to provide:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If some of your existing Spring Boot dependencies contain it by default, just exclude it. Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

That is it.