# Spring Boot without the web server

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot application that gets messages from a JMS queue and saves some data to a log file, but does not need a web server. Is there any way of starting Spring Boot without the web server?

Comment: If you don't need web then don't include it, when not included the embedded server will not start. You would only need the starter parent and add `spring-jms` (I guess) as a dependency. Then just start the application, no server will be started.

Comment: see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: You are wrong, I use only spring-boot-starter-batch, I do not include any tomcat or other server config in my pom.xml, however executing the application launches a web container. It must take a parameter somewhere.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Spring boot will not include embedded tomcat if you don't have Tomcat dependencies on the classpath.
You can view this fact yourself at the class `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` whose source you can find [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java).

The meat of the code is the use of the `@ConditionalOnClass` annotation on the class `EmbeddedTomcat`

---

Also, for more information check out [this](http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) and [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/) guide and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) part of the documentation

Comment: In its current version, the `gs-convert-jar-to-war/complete` Maven project *does* add an embedded Tomcat server, despite the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency declared with scope `provided`. This feels like a bug. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/25991789/923560

Answer (score 171):

### Spring Boot 2.x, 3.x

- [Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.main.web-application-type)

  ```
    spring.main.web-application-type=NONE 
    # REACTIVE, SERVLET
  ```
- or [SpringApplicationBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#web-org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType-)

  ```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MyApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE) // .REACTIVE, .SERVLET
                .run(args);
       }
    }
  ```

---

Where [WebApplicationType](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/WebApplicationType.html):

> - `NONE` - The application should not run as a web application and should not start an embedded web server.
> - `REACTIVE` - The application should run as a reactive web application and should start an embedded reactive web server.
> - `SERVLET` - The application should run as a servlet-based web application and should start an embedded servlet web server.

Comment: but you will loose actuator functionality. right?

Comment: @SimonLogic https://stackoverflow.com/q/43246714/1679903

Comment: If you want your application to have a stand-alone user interface, you should also call `.headless(false)` on the builder.

Answer (score 156):

if you want to run **Spring Boot 1.x** without a servlet container, but with one on the classpath (e.g. for tests), use the following, as described in the [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-web-environment):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
         SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyClass.class);
         app.setWebEnvironment(false); //<<<<<<<<<
         ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
    }
}
```

also, I just stumbled across this property:

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

Comment: Just adding the property to `application.properties` works perfectly fine.

Comment: You may need to add the dependency `org.springframework.security` in maven or gradle.

Comment: This works but is deprecated in Spring Boot 2.0. See this answer for the 2.0 version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394305/66686

Comment: Instead of `@Configuration` use a `@ComponentScan`, otherwise it wont get the other beans

Comment: FYI: This property `spring.main.web-environment` is now deprecated. Still works for Boot 2.1.1

Comment: Boot 2.x - application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);

Comment: What you're supposed to use these days is `spring.main.web-application-type=none`

Answer (score 57):

You can create something like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(false).run(args);
  }
}
```

And

```java
@Component
public class CommandLiner implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Put your logic here
  }

}
```

The dependency is still there though but not used.

Comment: Can we safely remove sprign-boot-starter-web dependency ?  For now making app non-web and removing this dependency causes exception ClassNotFound: javax.servlet.ServleContext

Comment: Please note, solution 1 is deprecated

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution. in your application.properties file. add the following property as mentioned by a previous answer:

> spring.main.web-environment=false

For version 2.0.0 of Spring boot starter, use the following property :

> spring.main.web-application-type=none

For documentation on all properties use this link :  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 12):

Use this code.

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
application.run(args);
```

Comment: With Spring Boot v2.4.4, Spring v5.3.5 this solution worked.  I tried setting the following properties (not together, one at a time) but none of them worked: spring.main.web-application-type=NONE, spring.main.web_environment=false, spring.main.web-environment-type=none, spring.main.web-environment=false.  I know the properties were being read because I could read them from main(...), and I could also change the port number using the same properties file.

Answer (score 11):

For Spring boot v2.1.3.RELEASE, just add the follow properties into application.propertes:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Answer (score 10):

If you need web functionality in your application (like `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` for REST calls) but you don't want to start a TOMCAT server, just exclude it in the POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

- Through program :

  ```
  ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =  new  SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApplicationMain.class)
  .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
  .run(args);
  ```
- Through application.properties file :

  ```
  spring.main.web-environment=false
  ```
- Through application.yml file :

  ```
  spring:
   main:
    web-environment:false
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Spring boot has many starters, some starters have an embedded web server, some don't. The following have the embedded web server:

```
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-jetty
spring-boot-starter-tomcat
spring-boot-starter-jdbc
spring-boot-starter-data-rest
...
```

Pick the one that meets your requirements and that does not have server support.

I only need to make restful json api request in my spring application, so the starter I need is

```
spring-boot-starter-json
```

which provide `RestTemplate` and `jackson` for me to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the spring-boot-starter dependency. This will not have the web stuff.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spring boot, Spring Web dependency provides an embedded Apache Tomcat web server. If you remove **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency in the pom.xml then it doesn't provide an embedded web server.

remove the following dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note: Starters should ideally be a parent POM, not a dependency

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use one of the "Getting Started" templates from spring.io site, but you don't need any of the servlet-related stuff that comes with the "default" ("gs/spring-boot") template, you can try the scheduling-tasks template (whose pom* contains spring-boot-starter etc) instead:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

That gives you Spring Boot, and the app runs as a standalone (no servlets or spring-webmvc etc are included in the pom). Which is what you wanted (though you may need to add some JMS-specific stuff, as someone else points out already).

[* I'm using Maven, but assume that a Gradle build will work similarly].

Answer (score 2):

Remove folowing dependancy on your pom file will work  for me

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Kotling here is what I used lately:

```
// src/main/com.blabla/ShellApplication.kt

/**
 * Main entry point for the shell application.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class ShellApplication : CommandLineRunner {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val application = SpringApplication(ShellApplication::class.java)
            application.webApplicationType = WebApplicationType.NONE
            application.run(*args);
        }
    }

    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {}
}

// src/main/com.blabla/command/CustomCommand.kt

@ShellComponent
public class CustomCommand {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @ShellMethod("Import, create and update data from CSV")
    public fun importCsv(@ShellOption() file: String) {
        logger.info("Hi")
    }
}
```

And everything boot normally ending up with a shell with my custom command available.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience on **spring boot > 2.5** ,

- **if you plan to build the application as a `jar` file**, in my opinion the solution of `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` should not be widely accepted and used, since it has only a limited scope of benefits.

  For asking to have spring boot without the web server, it means that you have from Spring either the dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` to build a spring web application or the dependency `spring-boot-starter-jersey` to build a `jax-rs` web application. Those dependencies pack inside the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` which will then bring the dependency of  `tomcat-embed-core` which is the actual tomcat server. This library is packed automatically inside and is of **size ~3.3 MB**. Even if you disable the server with the aforementioned property, you will still deliver your application `jar` file, containing the tomcat server inside.

  So the **con** of just using the aforementioned property is that the **deliverable jar** file will be some MB larger in size without any actual need.

  So if you want to have spring boot without the web server **just don't use the dependencies `spring-boot-starter-jersey` or `spring-boot-starter-web`** **since if you build your application as a `jar` file there is no reason to have those dependencies and not have an embedded server delivered.**

- **if you plan to build the application as a `war` file**, you should also not use the above property.
  In this case you will just need in your `.pom` the following configurations

  ```
  <packaging>war</packaging>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web or (spring-boot-starter-jersey)</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>pick the version that the server that already runs in production supports</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  ```
- Exceptional cases

  The property `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` should be in my opinion used for some exceptional cases like if we build some `web library` that needs the above dependencies but is not to be used like a web application, or we have some complex type of testing that needs those libraries although the application does not need any server to run. This type of usages are however rare.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @nayun oh answer above, but for older versions of Spring, use this code:

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
application.setApplicationContextClass(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.class);
application.run(args);
```