# Can Spring actuator be used with non-web Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-boot-actuator, application-monitoring

I have a Spring Boot application which listens for messages from an IBM MQ input queue, does some processing of the messages and then puts the messages to an output queue.

Can application like this utilize Spring actuator to monitor the application (e.g. heartbeat checking)? From reading the actuator documentation, it seems that it can only be used with Spring web applications?  Is my understanding incorrect? If so, could you please provide information on how to use actuator with non-web applications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to be available via HTTP when running in a web application, the Actuator's endpoints are also available over JMX in both web and non-web applications. MBeans for the Acuator's endpoints are published in the `org.springframework.boot` domain. Please see the [relevant section of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-jmx) for more details.

Comment: any example on how to access the MBeans programmatically? most examples I found suggest JConsole.