# Why the main method of spring boot application has returned but the application still can accept requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When i debug my spring boot application in Intellij IDEA, i found the main method of my spring application will return. When the main method return that means the process has finished, how can the spring boot application still accept requests?

Comment: Probably because it started some background threads that keep the JVM alive...?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Do you know where the application start those background threads?

Comment: When you launch your application, the web server/container is started by spring-boot. And the containers have thread pools and a lot of mechanisms to keep the application running, exactly to wait for incoming requests... You need to find in the documentation how to stop a spring boot application.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I just wander how the spring boot application works,because in other web frameworks Eg. Flask, NodeJs Express, When we run app.Run(), the application will block to accept requests,  which is easy to understand, because three is an event loop or listener to listen and accept connections, then the application can work.However, It seems that the spring boot application will never block to listen and accept connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you include a `web-starter` as a dependency for your application, Spring Boot knows it has to start an embeded servlet container (web server), unless you [explicitly tell him not to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394305/1199132):

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then when you do:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

The line `SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);` evaluates the classpath dependencies being included and detects the web dependencies. Then it knows you're configuring a web application and instantiates the servlet container, which keeps accepting requests until you explicitly terminate it.

**Samples:**

- https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

**See also:**

- [Spring Boot without the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105061/spring-boot-without-the-web-server)

Comment: So i guess the spring boot just start a tomcat server asynchronously and copy the resources to the work directory of the server, then the server can handle requests with those resources, am i right?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if it does copy the resources or just configure tomcat to point it to an external work directory with its resources instead, but that's how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot,you saved me from the confusion.