# How to Disable Spring Web MVC

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Hi I've just upgraded springboot from 2.0.5 to 2.1.8
First I got this error

```
The bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration and overriding is disabled.
```

So, I added this in `application.properties`

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

However I got different error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled, e.g. via @EnableWebMvc and @EnableWebFlux, in the same application.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.cermati.googolplex.GoogolplexApplication.main(GoogolplexApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled, e.g. via @EnableWebMvc and @EnableWebFlux, in the same application.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurationSupport.setApplicationContext(WebFluxConfigurationSupport.java:100) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

I want to enable only Web Flux and I've added `@EnableWebFlux`. How to disable the Web MVC?

Comment: Remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. You can only have one or the other not both.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394305/1038268

Answer (score 16):

As it's not recommended to run both MVC and WebFlux in the same application, You have to set the application type to `reactive` or `servlet` using the following:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
```

**NONE**

The application should not run as a web application and should not start an embedded web server.

**SERVLET**

The application should run as a servlet-based web application and should start an embedded servlet web server (MVC).

**REACTIVE**

The application should run as a reactive web application and should start an embedded reactive web server (WebFlux).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/WebApplicationType.html