# Can I use Spring Boot Starters just for dependency management?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Well, I was seeing Spring IO Platform for versioned management of my dependencies, then I went into the sources, as far I see it uses Spring Boot POMs under the hoods. So after that I was wondering, can I use the starters, since it's just POMs to shortcut the dependency declaration ?

Comment: the starters are just "known good sets".  so why not?

Comment: What he said. The reason they exist is so you can use them to manage dependencies. What's the confusion about?

Comment: Because I just want the poms, not the autoconfigure from Boot or embedded servlet container. If there is no problem my POMs will be glad to be more cleaner :D

Comment: Why not user Spring IO Platform's POMs?

Comment: Patform POMs are not like starters, they only have a set of compatibility versions, you still have to declare one dependency by one, currently I'm using both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the starters.

*Because I just want the poms, not the autoconfigure from Boot*
Then do not use `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) and [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-auto-configuration).

*Because I just want the poms, not the embedded servlet container*
Then do not use the `spring-boot-starter-web` starter, see the list of [Starter POMs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms).

If you need Spring MVC, then you have to declare the dependency or you use `spring-boot-starter-web` but without Tomcat, see e.g. [spring boot war without tomcat embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991789/spring-boot-war-without-tomcat-embedded)