# Spring Boot App works on local Tomcat but not on remote server

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

There are a lot of moving parts to this project, but I'll try to be brief and objective.

Basically, I have a Spring Boot application that compiles and runs fine on Netbeans with `Tomcat 7.0.63`. I also runs without issues when I drag and drop the `.war` file generated on Netbeans, directly to the `webapps/` folder on on the Tomcat directory.

However, when I try to deploy that same `.war` file to `Tomcat 7.0.63` running on a remote server, all I get is the Tomcat 404 Error page.

No errors are generated on Catalina.out and the application is deployed successfully, but it seems to just point to the root application folder instead of loading the Spring `DispatcherServlet`. The reason I say this is because if I add a sample `index.html` to the root folder, it will render instead of the 404 error.

Here is my `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class RecruitingDashboardApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(RecruitingDashboardApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(RecruitingDashboardApplication.class, args);
   }


}
```

And here is my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean 
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("dashboard");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

It's also worth noting that I don't have a `web.xml`. Everything is either auto configured by Spring Boot or Java configured through the above files.

Finally, since I know this will come up on the comments, here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>RecruitingDashboard</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Recruiting Dashboard</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.63</tomcat.version>
    <start-class>recruitingdashboard.RecruitingDashboardApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.22</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the cause of your problem, but [as described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) you need to mark the embedded Tomcat dependency as provided to stop it from interfering with servlet container that you're deploying to

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried to mark it as provided and I also tried excluding the tomcat dependency as described on this [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991789/spring-boot-war-without-tomcat-embedded). Both still yield the same result. Catalina.out does not show any signs of starting spring boot at all.

Comment: did you got the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but somebody else might stumble upon this problem like i did myself.

Deploying on local tomcat worked fine for me, but when deploying on remote tomcat on ubuntu i got the Tomcat 404 Error page aswell.

I also tried deploying with

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

but without the tomcat version (i was using Apache Tomcat/7.0.52. for the reference).

After deploying with properties:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>controllers.Application</start-class>
</properties>
```

it worked like it should.
Deploying with

```
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
```

worked aswell.