# Unable to start spring-boot application in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, spring-boot

**Overview**

I can run the application by using maven plugin of spring-boot but not run it with the IDE. The following lines give some detail about my program.

The application class is as follows:

```
package com.blss.retailServices.dataExportRouter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.velocity.VelocityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { VelocityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DataExportRouterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DataExportRouterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The exception stack trace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.blss.retailServices.dataExportRouter.DataExportRouterApplication.main(DataExportRouterApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I used @SpringbootApplication but to no avail.

**Question**

So I would appreciate it if anyone could help me solve this issue.

Comment: can you show your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I am guessing you have a `war` packaging project with Maven and you've flagged your servlet engine (tomcat) as provided.

Unfortunately, IntellIJ IDEA does not [add `provided` dependencies in the runtime classpath](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107048), that's why your project does not work when you run it from the IDE.

**UPDATE 7/30/2019**

As per Giorgio:

> They have added a checkbox in the Application Run Configuration to
>   "Include dependencies with 'Provided' scope"

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly my problem. I changed "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" dependency scope to compile and it was run properly.

Comment: They have added a checkbox in the Application Run Configuration to "Include dependencies with 'Provided' scope"

Comment: @Giorgio can you tell me in which version of IntelliJ you see the option?

Comment: @Ena I am using:
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.4445.78, built on April 10, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.4

Comment: Thank you this also solved my problem on Ubuntu 20.04, IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #IC-202.5792.28, built on June 18, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b944.12 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-37-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.plugins.watcher
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

Comment: Thanks solved my problem in Windows 21H1 and IntelliJ build 2021.2.3 (CE) & OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.12+7

Comment: Thank you so much., It solved my problem, Had a confusion why my code runs in STS and fails in Intellij IDEA