# Seploy Spring Boot application with embedded Tomcat to a regular Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ismailvohra/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-rest-api-in-spring-boot-a89e75cbb48b) to learn to create an API with spring boot. Thing is it uses an embedded Tomcat, and I would like to instead deploy it to the instance of Tomcat I'm running. When I build the war using bootWar and deploy it on my Tomcat, I get a 404 when trying to access the mapped route (/hello-world).

What do I have to change so that my war is built correctly?

Comment: Make `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` a provided dependency is all you need to do. Also make sure you are using a correct version of Tomcat to deploy on depending on your version of Spring Boot (2.x Tomcat 9, 3.x Tomcat 10) else it won't work. And you really don't want an external tomcat, use the embedded one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take some steps to remove Tomcat embedded webserver and make sure you package the project as a `.war`. Here are some steps you might want to follow to package the project accordingly - but this answer also goes into creating Spring Boot .war without Tomcat ([spring boot war without tomcat embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991789/spring-boot-war-without-tomcat-embedded)):

**1** Make sure you don't use the dependency `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>`. Remove this from your `pom.xml`.

**2** Package through Maven with a `.war` instead of `.jar` by default: In your `pom.xml`: `<packaging>war</packaging>`

**3** Create a class in a folder in your project where you override the `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MySpringBootApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**4** Make sure your Spring Boot application in the entry point is as normal:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is there a business case you use seperate Tomcat service? Embedded is one of the powers of Spring Boot.

**Pro tip** In modern IT enterprise infrastructures, containerized microservices are deployed through automated deployment systems. For Spring Boot and the non-Microsoft side, the deployment strategy is based upon the following commonly tools and steps:

1. **Spring Boot** application as a .jar with embedded Tomcat
2. **Docker**/containerize the Spring Boot application
3. **K8s**/Kubernetes for automated deployment processes and managing container applications

So much to learn about modern deployment strategies :)

[Learn how to Dockerize your Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/)

[Learn about deploying and managing containers after Dockerizing your Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-kubernetes/)

Comment: Honestly, it's because back in the day when I was programming, we used to package apps as .wer so that's the way I know. But maybe it isn't relevant anymore and I should keep the Tomcat-embedded version? I want to build a small project with a javascript client and a Java API, and since I used Tomcat to deploy the client anyway I wanted to do the same with my back, but maybe it isn't the way to go. I have never been in charge of releases and deployment so I'm a bit lost regarding what you're supposed to deliver to clients to be honest.

Comment: @GaetanL. If this is true, then I should stick to .jar and embedded Tomcat. You might even want to shift to Docker including embedded Tomcat - these are the more modern deployment scenarios. If you Dockerize your Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat, you're really up to speed.

Comment: @GaetanL. I've updated my answer with a more modern approach to Spring Boot deployment

Comment: No you don't need to remove it, you need to make it provided nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @GaetanL. scope: provided means you use it can use it during development but it will not be packaged inside when you build your project